# Finding the determinant of this general case matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm getting some headache when I want to find the result of this general matrix
[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq3uV.png).
Things works ok when I have one with numbers, but when it comes to this kind of matrix I'm totally lost. I use Laplace method to find the determinant (eliminating some lines and columns did not give me any result).

Comment: Look up [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) on the internet.

Comment: I read what you suggested to me, but I'm still in trouble with general formula, can you give me a hint or a first step to find the determinant of this circulant matrix..